# Brownian motion stopping time ( Durrett, Probability : Theory and Examples )

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

This is excercise 7.3.3 from durrett's book.

> Let $T_n$ be a sequence of stopping times.
> Show that $\sup_n T_n$is stopping time

The solution says,
let $R_n = max(R_{n-1},T_n), R_1 = T_1$. Then $R_n$ is stopping time, and as $n\rightarrow \infty$,
$R_n \uparrow \sup\limits_n T_n$.

There are two things I can't understand.

First, I know that maximum of two stopping time is stopping time, but how can we conclude from that $R_n$ is stopping time? What if $R_{n-1}$ is not a stopping time?

Secondly, how does the equality $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} R_n = \sup\limits_n T_n$ hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use induction to show that $R_n$ is a stopping time.

For any increasing sequence $a_n$ we have $\lim a_n=\sup_n a_n$.

Finally note that $(\sup_n R_n >a)=\bigcup_n (R_n >a) \in \mathcal F_a$ for all $a$ so $\sup_n R_n$ is  stopping time.

Comment: Thanks!I understood the induction part. However, how does $\sup\limits_n R_n = \sup\limits_n T_n$ hold?

Comment: @Dongri $R_n =\max \{R_{n-1},T_n\} \geq T_n$ for all $n$ so $sup_n R_n \geq \sup_n T_n$. On the other hand, $R_1=T_1\leq sup_n T_n $  and if you assume that $R_{n-1} \leq sup_n T_n $ the it follows that $R_n \leq sup_n T_n $ by definition of $R_n$. It follows by induction that $R_n \leq sup_n T_n $ for all $n$. Hence $sup_n T_n =sup_n R_n $.

Comment: So it is also based on induction. Thanks very much for the detailed explanations!